# Plesk 17: Calculate mailbox usage per domain

Tags: linux, bash, email, plesk

I am trying to export the list of emails that their quota is over 80% percent. I am quite new on Plesk scripts and this is where I am right now:

```
 mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow ` psa -NBe"
select m.mail_name, d.name, m.mbox_quota from mail as m 
left join domains as d on m.dom_id=d.id 
where m.mbox_quota <> -1 ;" | 
while read j i k; 
do echo $j"@"$i; 
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/mailmng-core --get-mailbox-size --domain-name=$i --mailname=$j; 
echo ""/$k;
done
```

Which will output something like this: (all emails with no unlimited quota)

> email@domain.com
>
> {actual_usage}/{quota}
>
> ....

How I can do the calculation in order to export only the email accounts that are over 80% and their usage percentage?

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```sql
SELECT 
    concat(mail.mail_name,'@',domains.name) AS 'Email address',
    mn_param.val AS 'Mailbox usage',
    Limits.value AS 'Mailbox limit' 
    FROM mail 
        LEFT JOIN mn_param ON mail.id=mn_param.mn_id 
        LEFT JOIN domains ON mail.dom_id=domains.id 
        LEFT JOIN Subscriptions ON domains.id=Subscriptions.object_id
        LEFT JOIN SubscriptionProperties ON subscriptions.id=SubscriptionProperties.subscription_id 
        LEFT JOIN Limits ON SubscriptionProperties.value=Limits.id 
    WHERE mn_param.param='box_usage' 
        AND Subscriptions.object_type='domain' 
        AND SubscriptionProperties.name='limitsId'
        AND Limits.limit_name='mbox_quota' 
        AND 'box_usage' > 'mbox_quota';
```

Use the last line (`AND 'box_usage' > 'mbox_quota';`) to make your own comparisons.